# Need a dictionary with exactly one key as method name php json

Tags: php, json

I am sending data to crm program from my website and it's give me fault message with my current below code.

```
$add_invoice[] = array(
        "scf_add_order"=>
        array ("session_id"=> $login['msg'],
                   "company_code"=>1,
                   "section"=> 1,
                   "card" => 
                    array ("_key_company" => "312",
                   "_key_customer" =>  
                    array ("customercode" => "$customercode"),
                    "invoiceno" => "INV000001",
                    "m_units" => array(array("_key_unit" => $stock_key))))
```

Above code add my all invoices to invoice.json file. There is no problem with it. But during send data i am getting below faultcode.

```
Array ( [faultcode] => Client.ValidationError [faultstring] => The value "'Need a dictionary with exactly one key as method name.'" could not be validated. )
```

When i delete [] from $add_invoice i can only send 1 invoice successfully. But i have to send more than 1. I couldn't figure out and i don't have any idea what i have to do. Also my other codes below.

```
$invoice =json_encode($siparis_ekle,true);
file_put_contents('invoice.json',$invoice);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $invoice);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($invoice))
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
$json=json_decode($result,true);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Then you have to send invoices one by one. API doc  must have given the valid format.

Comment: Normally, i supposed to add more than 1 because when i try to send json file manual (filling each value one by one and put in a loop) it's goes well and i can add invoices successfully.  I think i am missing something with array keys but not sure. Also there is no API doc for this. So i am totally blind

Comment: Ok, but without API doc, we wouldn't be able to help either. Maybe sending one by one is the only option.